# How to get the values of query parameters in Rest assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Below is my code

```
 RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8090/api";
 Response response1 = given().log().all()
                    .when()
                    .get("questions?exercise=C1&answers=true")
                    .then().log().all().extract().response();
```

How to get the values of query parameters **[exercise=C1&answers=true]**?
The values I want is **C1** and **true**

Comment: First off, I have never used this! 
I looked through the doc and I don't think you can get the query string from the Response object！

Comment: Since the query string belongs to the request body, I think, if you want to get it, you should at least use the Request object.

Comment: here the doc！https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/5.1.1/io/restassured/response/Response.html，I think you can take a closer look to see if there is a method that can help you implement the function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get request just from response. It is not the way how RestAssured is designed. However normally you also cannot get a response without knowing what request is. So you could just:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured
            .with()
            .baseUri("https://httpbin.org")
            .queryParams(Map.of("a", 1, "b", 2));
    Response response = RestAssured.with().spec(requestSpecification).get("/get");
    System.out.println(response.asString());
    System.out.println(((QueryableRequestSpecification)requestSpecification).getQueryParams());
}
```

which would result in

```json
{
  "args": {
    "a": "1", 
    "b": "2"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.16)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-62f61842-05465f9c198e631703c55c36"
  }, 
  "origin": "31.134.139.220", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?b=2&a=1"
}

{b=2, a=1}
```

Comment: you are correct but If I want to do assertions for the same would you please give me some examples so that I can follow

Comment: You should not do assertion of what the request parameters were **(because the opposite would mean you are testing RestAssured, not your service)**. You should do the assertions of what response content is. Your service is responding with some business objects or any sort of valuable data so you basically need to assert how well that valuable data matches the request. So you just take the parameters you have already used for request and take the response data and test if the logic of your service works as expected.